# Массивы без указаного размера

Tags: c++

Нужно получить некоторое количество информации от пользователя.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);


    printf("Введите: Текст, \n");

    int index[];
    char user[];
    char name[];

    int i=0;
    while(scanf("%s,%d,%s",&name,&index,&user)==1)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %s",name[i], index[i], user[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Но компилятор выдает ошибку

```
error: array size missing in
```

Почему-то требует явно указать размер. Как я понимаю эти данные лучше хранить в структуре, но там вроде разрешен только 1 массив без указания размера.

Comment: Почем вопрос помечен тегами [С] и [С++] одновременно. Так С или С++?

Comment: Что такое `scanf("%s,%d,%s",&name,&index,&user)` за которым идет вдруг `scanf("%s %d %s",name[i], index[i], user[i])`. Что тут вообще имеется в виду?

Comment: IMHO, в этом случае лучше бы подошёл динамический список структур  `{int index; char user[USER_MAX]; name[NAME_MAX]; }`

Answer (score 6):

> Почему-то требует явно указать размер.

Разумеется, требует. В языке С нет и никогда не было именованных массивов с изменяющимся во время выполнения размером. Размер именованного массива в языке С должен быть известен *заранее*, в момент его определения. Это размер может быть величиной времени выполнения, но он должен быть известен к моменту определения массива. Точка.

Если вам обязательно нужен массив переменного размера, то выход тут только один - ручное выделение массива в динамической памяти (и перевыделение, при необходимости увеличения размера).

Answer (score 1):

к тому, что сказал @AnT

в вашем примере есть ошибка инициализации

```
int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);

    int num; // размер массива
    cout << "Введите размер массива: ";
    cin >> num; // получение от пользователя размера массива

    printf("Введите: Текст, \n");

    // динамическое создание одномерных массивов на num элементов
    int *index[] = new int[num];
    char *user[] = new char[num];
    char *name[] = new char[num]; 

    int i=0;
    while(scanf("%s,%d,%s",&name,&index,&user)==1)
    {
        scanf("%s %d %s",name[i], index[i], user[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```