# Проблема с отладкой в CLion'e

Tags: mingw, gdb, clion

Есть такой код:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

const int N = 100;
int ar[N][N];

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

Ставлю точку останова и пытаюсь посмотреть содержимое всего массива, gdb выбрасывает ошибку:

```
../../../../src/gdb-7.11.1/gdb/gdbtypes.c:4575: internal-error: copy_type: Assertion `TYPE_OBJFILE_OWNED (type)' failed.
A problem internal to GDB has been detected,
further debugging may prove unreliable.
```

Но при отладке этого кода все хорошо:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>

const int N = 100;
int ar[100][N];

int main() {

    return 0;
}
```

MinGW-w64 5.0
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1

Comment: почитайте здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/567064/199793

Comment: У меня код компилируется и работает. Создавать массивы размера константа считаю возможным.